# Timestamp code for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I am using this script in order to put a time stamp in column B when someone edits in a row. However, I need it to place the time stamp if someone edits a row in column A. I don't need it to place a stamp every time someone makes a change on the rest of the sheet. Can someone tell me what I need to change on this script in order for the time stamp to only be placed in columb B if the cell to the left of it in column A is edited?

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-05:00", "MM/dd/yy, h:mm a");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

Answer (score 3):

The "if" conditional should check whether the edited column has number 1. So it's `...getColumn() == 1` instead of `...getColumn() != 2`.

In addition, I simplified the script which wasn't particularly well written. Using the event object, and its range property, eliminates the need for most of that code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1) {                // check if the edit was in column A 
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date());   // put timestamp one cell to the right
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks - this really worked (the original code).

The advantage of using **getColumn() != 2** is that it will change the timestamp when *any* cell is edited, other than the timestamp itself in Column 2 (which would produce an endless loop.)

Instead of **GMT-5**, I used Google's **"America/New_York"**, which seems to adjust for DST. See https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates.